# MySQL Query Restarting Every 60 Seconds?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange problem. I'm running a MySQL query against a very large table from PHP. The query time is over a minute, but that's not my problem. It looks like PHP is resending the query every 66 seconds.

```
show processlist;
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------
| Id     | User    | Host              | db       | Command | Time | State         | Info                                                   
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------
| 150018 | root    | localhost         | amrs     | Query   |   32 | Sending data  | /*DEREK*/select ctlno, count(*) AS count from (omitted)
```

A few minutes later, I checked again:

```
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------
| Id     | User    | Host              | db       | Command | Time | State         | Info                                                   
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------
| 150018 | root    | localhost         | amrs     | Query   |  188 | Sending data  | /*DEREK*/select ctlno, count(*) AS count from (omitted)
| 150021 | root    | localhost         | amrs     | Query   |  122 | Sending data  | /*DEREK*/select ctlno, count(*) AS count from (omitted)
| 150023 | root    | localhost         | amrs     | Query   |   56 | Sending data  | /*DEREK*/select ctlno, count(*) AS count from (omitted)
```

I have not reloaded the page or anything. set_time_limit(0) is called near the beginning of the script. The annoying part is, the page seems to be linked to the most recently run one. So if I kill 150018, nothing bad happens, but if I kill 150023 before another one is spawned, the page comes up with a "Query execution interrupted" error. 150018 will eventually finish running on its own but it doesn't do any good because the script/page won't receive it.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: show full processlist gives the following (with some lines removed for brevity and confidentiality):

```
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------
| Id     | User    | Host              | db       | Command | Time  | State        | Info 
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------
| 147385 | root    | localhost:44560   | amrs     | Sleep   | 14021 |              | NULL
| 150248 | root    | localhost         | NULL     | Query   |     0 | NULL         | show full processlist
| 150251 | root    | localhost         | amrs     | Query   |     1 | statistics   | /*DEREK*/select ctlno, count(*) AS count from (snip)
+--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you show us the result of this command: `show full proceslist;` just after executing the query? (open 2 connections, #1 = your query, #2 = this query)

Comment: It looks the same as I would expect. I omitted a few lines related to other queries, as I did above but I tacked it on above.

Comment: can you show the table structure? there is no where clause?

Comment: I'm omitting some stuff for confidentiality's sake. Why does the table structure or where clause have anything to do with the query restarting? It's a valid query that I can run on the mysql prompt and get a response back after a few minutes.

Comment: do you have a cronjob that runs that query ?

Comment: No. It's being run from a web site. As I mentioned above, the page is not reloading.

Comment: Are you using a connectivity library, maybe PDO etc? Some libraries allow for a 'resume on fail' setting, where they will blindly reattempt the query if it fails. I would check your mysql.log to see why the query is being aborted

Comment: In PHP change the max execution time for running script or execution. It is generally by Administrator [Web hosting provider] just contact him and he will solve this problem..

Comment: what is the way you interact with database? PDO, mysql, mysqli?

Comment: No connectivity library, just plain old mysql_connect and mysql_query. This is a locally hosted server. max_execution_time is set to 600, max_input_time is 60. The beginning of the script calls set_time_limit(0)

Comment: Think you'll need to paste in your PHP code if you want someone to be able to answer it properly...

Comment: What happens if you run the query through MySQL Query Browser/command line/phpMyAdmin/other tool of choice?

Comment: "...max_input_time is 60..." i would check this :)

Comment: I inherited this code from someone else so it's a MESS and would need to be cleaned up before being posted. Also, it's a government project so I have to be careful about what I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem a few times before, and your problems sound very similar to what I was experiencing working with a previous web site.

Are you going through a proxy server when going to the web site?

What was happening with my site, was that the queries from a particular set of users within the same company were being directed through their proxy server, which was deciding for itself that if no response was received within 60 seconds, then it would just issue the web request again, without informing the client browser that this was happening!

So, with certain long running queries taking over a minute to execute, I'd see the queries start to compound on each other, and I'd end up looking at a process-list with loads of identical queries running, each separated by almost exactly 60 seconds!

The resolution to this was to get the client to by-pass their proxy server for our site.

A second instance of this exact same problem was resolved when the client upgraded their proxy server to the latest version.

I'm sorry, but I can't remember what proxy server was in use in either case, as it was quite a few months ago, and I have slept since then :-/

Comment: And something you say confirms my suspicions, in that if you kill one of the older queries you see no response (as the proxy server has given up on that page and moved on), and if you kill the single (or most recent?) query, then you see the response in the browser, as that is the only one that the proxy server is waiting for...

Comment: I think it was Squid. Hope you're well anyway, former boss of mine!

Comment: It may well have been, but I'm unsure. Unfortunately, the proxy being on the clients site meant we had little control over it. And I'm doing very well ta, hope you and your good lady are too! :)

Comment: Hmm, given the symptoms and my knowledge of networking, this sounds like a plausible solution. Unfortunately, there isn't really any way for me to know... I work for the government and there are elements of the network we aren't made aware of. But this happened from at least two different computers on two different networks (one NIPR, one CIPO, if you have any knowledge of government networks). I'll try opening the page from the server if I get a chance and see what happens.

Comment: Would you believe me if I said that the clients I had trouble with were government too? Hospitals to be precise... With 40+% of their users still using IE6... Grrr...